# Flutter: Preview one or more images from the phone gallery?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I am using the camera plugin in flutter with a custom camera preview interface but I would want to include into the interface a list at the bottom of the screen a list of photos currently inside my photo gallery....Is there a plugin for flutter that I can use to preview photos from my photo gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found a plugin that you were asking for. The plugin is called [photo_manager](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/photo_manager).

From the photo_manager Readme:

> A flutter api for photo, you can get image/video from ios or android.
>   If you just need a picture selector, you can choose to use photo library , a multi image picker.

I hope this helps and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

check image_picker plugin for Flutter

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#-readme-tab-